# How to Autogenerate multiple getters/setters or accessors in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, code-generation

Before I start, I know there is this post and it doesn't answer my question: [How to generate getters and setters in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017/how-to-generate-getters-and-setters-in-visual-studio)

In Visual Studio 2008 there is the ability to auto generate getters and setters (accessors) by right clicking on a private variable -> Refactor -> Encapsulate Field...

This is great for a class that has 2 or 3 methods, but come on MS!  When have you ever worked with a class that has a few accessors?

I am looking for a way to generate ALL with a few clicks (Eclipse folks out there will know what I am talking about - you can right click a class and select 'generate accessors'.  DONE.).  I really don't like spending 20 minutes a class clicking through wizards.  I used to have some .NET 1.0 code that would generate classes, but it is long gone and this feature should really be standard for the IDE.

UPDATE: I might mention that I have found Linq to Entities and SQLMetal to be really cool ideas, and way beyond my simple request in the paragraph above.

Comment: If you have that many fields that it takes 20 minutes, perhaps your class is trying to do too much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, you really need to install [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) to get approximately the same amount of refactoring support as you are used to in Eclipse.

However, Resharper gives you a dialog very similar to the one you are used to in Eclipse:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I have an "info class generator" application that you can use an excel sheet and it will generate the private members and the public get/set methods.

You can download it for free from my [website](http://iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/info-class-generator.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In 2008 I don't bother with Encapsulate Field.  I use the new syntax for properties:

```
public string SomeString { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a macro. There are also addins (like ReSharper, which is great but commercial) capable of doing that quickly.