# Is it possible to auto-generate property accessors in Visual Studio 2015 for c++/cx?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, refactoring, c++-cx

It would be great to auto generate property code from a member variable (much like VisualAssist or Resharper functionality for accessor functions). I found these questions that are considerably outdated:

[How to generate getters and setters in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017/how-to-generate-getters-and-setters-in-visual-studio/29917170#29917170)

[How to generate automatic properties (get, set) for Visual Studio 2008 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622298/how-to-generate-automatic-properties-get-set-for-visual-studio-2008-c/1622396#1622396)

and this question which is for C#:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864873/generate-property-in-one-line-in-visual-studio-2015

but I cannot seem to find any definitive answer for C++ in VS2015.

Has anyone found a way to do this? I would prefer either built-in VS functionality or a reliable 3rd party plugin (for purchase is ok).

Thanks,

Comment: It is C++, it is supposed to be hard.  If it wasn't then anybody could do it and we can't have that.  If it is available at all then you'll have to find it in the Class Wizard.  But I wouldn't trust it too much to know about C++/CX semantics.  You'll have to try.

Comment: Well, I'm not having too many problems with the language itself. I've worked with C++/C++11 for many years and the transition to C++/CX isn't too bad so far.

Mostly I'm looking for convenience functions of the UI/dev environment.

Comment: The title talks about C++/CX, the question mentions C++. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible to an extent.  If I haven't misunderstood, then yes there is a way to shorten properties if the get and set doesn't do anything fancy:

```
public:
property int MyValue{
    int get(void){return _myValue;}
    void set(int value){_myValue = value;}
}

private:
int _myValue;
```

can easily be shortened to:

```
`property int MyValue;`
```

side note:  If your property needs the PropertyChanged event you will have to do it the long way:

```
public:
property int MyValue{
    int get(void){return _myValue;}
    void set(int value){
        _myValue = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue");
    }
}

virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged

private:
int _myValue;

void NotifyPropertyCHanged(Platform::String^ prop){
    PropertyChangedEventArgs^ args = ref new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop);
    PropertyChanged(this, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a purely C++ perspective, and assuming that you have no objection to using non-standard Microsoft language extensions, you can use `__declspec(property`

```
struct Entity {
    //**************************************************** PROPERTY: heading
    float heading_get()      const;
    void  heading_set(float value);
    __declspec(property(get = heading_get, put = heading_set)) float heading;

private:
    float _heading = {};
};

float Entity::heading_get()      const { return _heading;  }
void  Entity::heading_set(float value) { _heading = value; }

void usage() {
    Entity entity;
    entity.heading = std::clamp<float>(entity.heading, 0, 360);
}
```

For simple uses, you can streamline this with a macro:

```
#define PROPERTY(TYPE, NAME)                    \
    TYPE _##NAME;                               \
    TYPE get_##NAME() const { return _##NAME; } \
    void set_##NAME(TYPE _) { _##NAME = (_);  } \
                                                \
    __declspec(property(get = get_##NAME, put = set_##NAME)) TYPE NAME
```

It's not pretty, but it will give you **true properties** (*ish*)

[image: screenshot from Visual Studio]